# How to remove multiple legends from a Plotly subplot in Python

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-express

I am working on the Iris Dataset. To have the same data as me use this code -

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

data = load_iris()

features_df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns = data.feature_names)
target = pd.DataFrame(data.target, columns = ["species"])
target.replace(dict(zip(np.unique(data.target), data.target_names)), inplace = True)

df = pd.concat([features_df, target], axis = 1)
```

Using this code I am able to generate 4 scatterplots as subplots -

```
fig = make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 2)

plots_xy = [("sepal length (cm)", "petal length (cm)"), ("sepal width (cm)", "petal width (cm)"), ("sepal length (cm)", "sepal width (cm)"), ("petal length (cm)", "petal width (cm)")]
plot_coords = list(itertools.product([1,2], repeat = 2))

for index, plot in enumerate(plots_xy):
  fig.add_traces(px.scatter(data_frame = df, x = plot[0], y = plot[1], color = "species").data, rows = plot_coords[index][0], cols = plot_coords[index][1])
  fig.update_xaxes(title_text = plot[0])
  fig.update_yaxes(title_text = plot[1])

fig.update_layout(width = 1200, height = 900)
fig.show()
```

The plot -

[image]

As you can see, the legends are getting repeated here. How can I stop this and only have one legend for the whole plot?

Answer (score 0):

```py
names = set() fig.for_each_trace(lambda trace: trace.update(showlegend=False) if (trace.name in names) else names.add(trace.name))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).